# Decode a String File in Java encoded in iOS (Base64)

Tags: java, ios, rest, encoding, decode

I am making a `RESTFul` service in Java that receives a `Base-64` String from a `iPhone`.

But I am unable to make the file again at the server end.

I used some of the following codes but all of them are not working for me.

**ONE**

```
File fileOut = new File("/home/xyz/fileOutPNG.png");
FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(fileOut, Base64.decodeBase64(fileString));
```

**TWO**

```
File fileOut = new File("/home/xyz/fileOutPNG.png");
FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(fileOut, fileString.getBytes());
```

**Three**

```
BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();

File fileOut = new File("/home/xyz/fileOutPNG.png");
FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(fileOut, decoder.decodeBuffer(fileString));
```

Can someone show me how can I create image back.

for reference `fileString` contains the following encoded string.

```
"iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGQAAAClCAYAAACqVlhFAAAAHGlET1QAAAACAAAAAAAAAFMAAAAoAAAAUwAAAFIAAA P0RNzfgAAD1tJREFUeAHsnHmQFcUdxxcPVKLxSNR4RNSQMgke3IfBsGoqGkuUEtcFxXW5wRLPWF5RVxPUJKCmNDHGVYhbyKHhZgUxYjQhBjFIPEiCBmJUEIgGF1Fg2ZfPb v1q98Ob95098y8fWvlj191z8yvf9e3r numbJMJlP2fyqdGLQKGIsWLTpi3rx550O3LViw4In58 cvg9ZBW6FMgD7i i3oeWgKdD1lzpo9e/ZBn8eKVBRA6uvr9yH45xLMh6C3oWDQfa6bkLMKcH4GnVZTU7PH5wGgVAFZuHBhb4L2KLQlIRAKAfe gDN37twT2jIwiQMiNZXgV9IiXo4AYTU8dQTxVtKLAK8HwewEHb548eIvkB4AHQmdIMDCcynyfgQ9Bf0rQnY9z8vbIjCJAkIQBkJvhgRLWskUAjuEAH8lbrAAqhPyRkKzoO1QvtYj406vuLqKWT4RQKQW4/jv8gUFAJ7mfuXMmTP3S8sxWtnB6BmDnuX5bODebxjHDk1Lf5JyYwFCkPfE2RuhzwKBaOR6GoE6MUljbWShtxxaErBHWs9/sGewjYzW5PEGJDt1/X0ex2dJd9KaTolugn8qtr0UtI WVCdjVGvbF6bfCxAC/m0c3aCdJQBrobPCFLXS/XYAMAI75V1GjzGvY vxrWRTwZgXfJjPYByrhIKD6KN0X/vn4y Fe9h7FPQspEHZBCinloJ92gYnQHBgHE7JC5lxbBv5Ki2wVPMyHcf O/LYf2Yp2WwNSBYMA4SkG TdoZScsbGFLmwQtktFMr58yr0zbMoWg8cKEIy/RDkgjrzFNPJrxTAwDR3ZMVCvHmyTl880dLnKjASE2tMfAHYoQASMo10VlRq/AIBPGpSN Hpca9tZEJA5c Z8FaM3KjDWl4LRSQUt21I Vf6tIt8hKfk ckIBWbp06V4YJ8vipq/9hHw3HyWlXIYKdpHyMcNYWdua9oYCgpG3a0MxfEiaho4ePfrLo0aNOpV04JgxY4ZCQ6ABUA/uHZimbnybEPB1UJr6CsnOCwj960kYuNMYSa35VSEhPs qq6sPItgjoBkEfCOUiaC1PH8MqqDsvj46w8pkl4BeNP6Sbpg1a9aXwvjTvJ8PkHYYpLuqNVwn1q OHDnyZII6FdoORYEQ9nwLQN5P WOSCg6VsCN NkDNXTSt5uGkZLvI2Q0QDLrYGCUphiUyRx87duxRBHB6ARB28ext6HloLrQAehF6BwoDZgfP7h0 fPgBLk6H8dITjFe ywvwKWG8ad1vAUh2IJf9azOQT0tCMWNDNYFryBNY6YYmAFZ5oW5IAo6Mc F9ENqUR8673Ds9rq3ZrktmWsb/hXFlupZvAQiGDFPG7JRm7CpQ81dUVLQnkLV5AvgiXc7ZZWVl7TS/TR5Ze1O2inR1QO4udN1kI6MQDz6frWIgPUTPQvxJP9OAtKPJvqGMmRJHGcHqQOAWBYK2nqAlsifB2tReyL8W Z8EdDzgA7T2FRD09vNM/SztfA4QgDhTgbErzp6GtAyCVB8I1LN0TYcl7RCThG i5/WArvvi6CEOshVtuq1GYnFkHHkuZXOA0DpmGCPIz3EREuQlOA8HAvQYIO0Z5EvqGl0HQjIZyA3 tMSrYsiXmabMLs2M65YYsnIxtpHRzCx7GSjXSwgDbQrn46EbGaoDQ35K3C4kn57gPfR0AIQ/KN07uPbu/6mUtxpASFcH9aV13QwICmXTyTTRzQDU3kch3cfhBOS/KijPpdkygjaOGzfuYHTLzM20lDfI7x3ks7nmZOSxKiYyuHe2KReXxwDyuFL a1 hOP 4Csamyy /PPZxH1dbpFVgQ6Oy4zpXGYafmORekAHkB Z mqkBRO PX ijkK7q6wShyQSCwFT7yEmiDDZMNHaQbqZieG0vA0iNqah0Yc8kYVuUjDLZaDJKSZt813Bw/BEVhJXFGDfCnMMOGeRzXSeVZXwYb6H7tIr KjYN8uJYiD JZ3JcZrBSuspHKM53gD6GTN9d4SMnyTLYcqey51Uf2TKWEpvcZIdYpX7OrAyFdylAHvcxHMcrlPOytOE1kProDiszYsSIjtiR60LlfSWMt9B9YrPSxIcWk oWhNghgMjh5VjzbRzPvXcwdjxUyMFiPsOuZZBptVf46CY200x8SGt8ZLiUEUBWGIU0yQtcChtenM6tK9Ffe00KjKwkU yqMYBQUZ70kS0gmPiQTvGR4VJGAHnPKGRhzflYDw7vDe00jpMmtkfh4kg XirHOcqu1/LxRN2jkg438aHLejqKP 5zASR3UJo1G ePXbLTXdMtbG3N2VUwGLwoHq8A2R58bnMNCIMMIKTLbcrE4RFAzBt6xmcRjcGyu3J6XRxjki4r yjKtsz48eP3cdVBfL6nYuQ1W3PR2QIQnw8pZXNJOZ2IwV26dDm2W7dul3Tv3v10KNYBB2VbRvbxXYIjvHRZpylA/ula3pW/BSA H7XQQvoop9e4GhDk79y5c3tAWAtlsrSTdKaAFOSNupZdSGVbxueNHUBOV4B4jUNRdurnAsguoxDlzkf0aSEnKqc3auE eYJ/kgLDgCLpR127dnWadMhamrKtycceYqP3Rlb6yHApI4DkTiYyy riUlh4g/20rLi6ytD8PXr0KA8BREB5D7LuwphwfEcB4jW EZ8qU2FJn9W2ppEXQHIfadJCvD64wWk5ZGBmWrEOGwDIeQUAyfD8QdtAYNMVyq7FtuU0HzG5zgBCfoZ lkZeAKk3Ckmv9FFCTZxlHCd/h48MU4bBvFMhQHj2KXSE4S UYtNsYxdpTSHesGeAUKvi89MwvqTuCyAPKIW/9BGMs7omxhr4eI/Zg4A3QHr8aJGnlUQGVwZw7NpqAJHZoI9vxOYFFZ9RPjJcysi0brRS LxLYcPLTOtoHNcLed3NM5 UgC8rBAjP/h21E4k9lxkwSD QUyo thCbzSY xCr1T CkhfQyCkm3 W7f4vQSFYDpPs6bMgT8oQhAZCw5x/AHU/l8DVveVPbcG SxueZzjG p2DQSG6 NLhtdhqcse1pxm1Ls1bQZO85WAZDW4v3pAmCMiwKEseYp40QwZSHxUmVLoyyhBHlsronJFSour9iUictTJgJQulgpvtNXKEH4iwrE8qhuJUwP7xt9owDh XZotykw yCHYMMHxg4qyuQwPVH36aLmqLhMjOJP4nkzICi 2igm/4avYJzvSyByYwn5CT6yeFvfn2A3RYFCKxmq5cvCJjbMN2CQyi6m1YxMy5G8dE/ERD5SMntFZwR50rg2LeQYo1hSQPEelAnIL1RAMlwP8TEcMP4WBQjPW xxoHdCQPdYH91ShlXeahWTD1esWFGUXdBmQMQAlP9JGfBzX0ey60evqsDsABTnjS C/YQFIFv79u3b/FMb9N2idMpLaugYY MbsVhq4kEFTfyDpTAbcoBQI QXFGYp/qM4M4rsfrZ e5eT6VeFGZHvPt3R9RaAZHr27FlJ8B8IgLHcZyHR2JGdXekfJBTtF085QOSHLACi/wlyozHQJ80uOgY/Vfst7yyH28hjYD/TBpD /fvnjvtkQXlt2LBhh9roCOOhRTyhKmdRZlfGlhwgcgMj9AkUOVIa6x9XtJROBGlNoPZu4fr6qBpMV3SIDSDCQzdp1tHki6vdZl7GWZtUTv0TB/m9lOktLrYplxRPC0BkPwRD9J9Bb4qrKHveVq8pmeBtZmy5n66sp7zI5dNDsNfagDJgwIAMciYxzfY6k6x1478 ZbJG3tP087TzLQARZRikW0lDUn9tIPhV1N7c 0Gg1XxIQBdKULl/Nelw0pH9 vV7zQaQXr16vZVEoPC9H2RahqSVSch1kbEbIDTZAzBEn/Wd6yKwEC9BPhBgfki6GTItJTSVmm8DCDxN0sUV0h31jIq3D36vVoAso4zzJ3dReqKe7waIFMCoFj bYZC7LEqQy/NrrrlmP1rBYECZB VWZIMgVVZW2gIia1vnudgQ5MXniQqMxjjvYkHZLtd5AREBGLdQGdhA/hsugm15ZRUWcOQPDiOhn9CCJnP9JPnpVVVVNu8iBrS7bXUG Zjyf1/5Kt C3BPkKdZ1KCDyT0WM3KQMfXPJkiWxZjA TtEdbbDptmTJ3kd dlalp/srpfvykZVEmVBARHj2E2F9COIZpsKxZzIuhgPGIhtA4GmEnCqMfHpBhfuHqnQfA9AJLvYlzVsQEFFG871FGSwzj2mAkvp3EsZRgnyXJSAZ3u6tl2iktePLn5VvTfh6vtHbWmkkIBgm369PVoYLKFOL1VIAo8IWEPisfq2UBwzx6drWAkHrtQFElqLbY/C8ACj13E99B41aH3XowQzqkq7TzuXLZ3/K9lftS2sO4kEbrQCRQiGgrJSvVYNCk7yWPQ4CvcW2lRQ64ciY2Bsgcqf9s6CkfpLEJR7WgBhQqE11unaR/5AuLdY7QJTBgPGCLSC0qOo88uRHAFdC t R0k3dnofXKSZJl/dRLmPKj3FGHNL0iM9hbRuHmNLeZwsIfFO0TFpFR zUW9Ris/wIukrzlUreB5DmMoByAU5tgTQo67OOJrrkACBVDoCsk CyKLgvttwE6cVSsfUdWrn3Hx7SBs4bEDEMx47DwT9CGhTJrwSwwWGruK5OAUbYAWw9oOfykyZNqpHA57FrOnbFOnvsarsrfyxARJkEHcelf27IE4C/A9qYuG/45eXlewHKDttWcvPNNwcryHvSol2D0xr8sQExRvOGeyROTwYUvfVpAiOfzc2EBrIs8UVTxiUFjFW2gAwaNMjold ITyjG9NzFl0K8iQFilMh NMDIFqjedTMBklTuv0Sg7iG9ECBPlv7elA9L /TpM9MWEMacTG1t7SOyHhcmr1TvJw6IcTQ7u7mboOu9FQ2Mzkurehd6HXoJWgI9By2HZI9iww033JAbI2yAAZSi/ePK JxEmhogxjg5zySLlLSaWgL7PqSBsM5PnDjRCRBAWytjj7GjraSpAxIIRDvAkZ80j82ON6 Q1 eKQwGqq6tzBUQWG4cF9BfbX2d9zgXScJBl8MMA5hRA i6pfNOXI8aa/lDnqVOnHkyt/9imu1I863v37u01iUjDTxuZJQGIjaHCw7jwsgq2bYuZUUo/M4jyta0BUucBiHRd97YVUNoUIIBxmw8gUgZQ6gutBEfV3GI9b1OAENRKX0Cy5T4jvR8q2feTNgUIY0jXmICYcUe 5L1TvkMpVs231dOmAMl yGOCmkT6Pq1uaCmNL/8DAAD//z3kdT8AAAbkSURBVO2dX4wdUxzHrz/1X pPhQcSkqWttZvdvfvH2oTrQWwaVLBBCIqXkkh5EJ7aEFkqjXqQ0iayGjSpEkVToX2oP5GiGtlGGyVaLZqGsljVrbW 382ZdkzvnTvn3HPOnDkzDydzZ 7c8/vzOb9zfnPmzNzSxMREKUulXC7vRpnQWTo7OzegXOKCHzIFgw4DiA91wgjV9Q8 P93X13dqmmCyCOTVkBO1Roqo94eOjo7bSqXSUWmAUQLS09NzbldXVxvKObaVhtOeNAxkEjKgfAw5PbbtkwLS3t7eCyW3RhzyPZR/Csem2VAecuZG5JuIkkN1wrZVaHjNNmyjjMRABgYGjoEj9sQ442cMjBXTisNB18TocMiRus B3NVokJebti8xkLa2ttMSGPkXFO83qTTqb02ghzEwkP01yiPd3d0XmLAzMRAOclDkxwTOGIPT5phQlnW2tLScnkAHk0DCdW CrfMwpp6ty97EQCgQXdICCWcsYjenS9FwPdDhgIQeYQea nwQ gyhzAjrqfJZCkhra vJELpTwhnvmMjrIf8nCR1MQahW7zj0WtTc3HycCgz RgoIf4AomSXpjC9w/lRVBav9DvVtkdShmvOMHUM3xpRZyWZpIHQQBD4v4xCcP7 aY1WPoVFskJGfxrnQcV2lUjlW1kYlIDDwJJTtEob gqzkTFnlap0PwKskZBuLhHo6AMrCWjbUOq4EhJVBmSvrKRT5fmUtJWSPo96lkbpTc3odPcbReC6VsU8ZiIDyRh2Foo66V0a5WudC5qCk3KgeNve3oes6oZYt0eMNAeGUgqRjDnD6JaqE7D66Apn026bza8l6PKmNDQGhEACRnQ7fw8nJpApWOw8yrUwwSja2WjB4fAwN8eJqtkSP6QByp4Lin/f29p4YVSbpPuS9qSAzzmE2vtuYJOtqGAgugk6Bc/YrOGilyj0HyJmCsldBng2nx8pIknU1DIStGoJeV3TQEkA5OmlkCFk3KcqKdZbFOufG2asFCIwZUDWIMDmTHKdk8J2Ycf5OVZZDv3sosCm61QKkqanpeBg70oDBu5Cv3x4XLUwEcM6nDchwJUICPZZWm/PSAoSU0dJf0OCsHahjEI7vR33TEREXYnsVyjM4/ruG gNnuLL9IDqDoQ0I0zoPHWYD3DB8d1bQdWkDIqLkrQKK/Jox9ACfBVfzWoEAxgwU124e2WjlOmRMXs1rBcIoQf8/v4gS SiBz0Z5M087EJFxfVVAkYeCrutu7UDEWNIHIP8WUOSgoHdZYQQIoQDGkgKIHBD4a5tJIFMhIMmyIR0Doi917DcGRESJ8pRKXqPLKBCRdXEFhi8t2LgdxoEgc AAb9wQT2SMGgciui7Ze 95BbjbChBEyXS0YD6hlFdHJ7V7ixUgRRqcrCHiOuR9m0CmIUJ LaIkFs7L1oCIjOv AkhtIOjaF1oFIp7C2lxAqQ4FQB62CoRRwoVyBZCaQO6xDkR0XcsLKEdCwaB bSpA AgYgDSyKCJpGpmp89h7pAJEpMEPFFHy/yjBgoeLUgPCZZUAMlxAOQyFK1BSA8Iower5Kwogh4HQJ6kCEQP8igLKJJR9TgDBYrjzAeTvAkr5WyeAUAnAWFwAKW9yBgjX7QJIrtdz4Sp9nTNAiiiZHENecw0IZ4P35bjrGnIKCJXB1MFdOQayzDkgVAhAXsoplMVOAuHDoADyUQ6huAlERAkX2W3MGRR3gRAKV4IDyLs5guI2EBEpfAT6uTxA4e1bJ8cQKhUtIvsa9RkMgCzIDBAqKt6rMuwrFAB5MFNAqCwzMCiu42lf5 4kwq47MgeECrOgC7sZkfKHT9GCHuCyzAKh4nyGHUCGPYFyMHgZzxEDaNAKs7AVqfHbHkDZHPg700BoBBffof99MctQoP9ab4AEUABkTYahrPcKCI1BH3wGgMT9WYBzmVWoAW33DggNQvY1J2SkywCiuvFV5VNoQ bHkKBlcSvWen2TRShcJOcdEBqEKJmXRSAY2Gd5CQQweCs4iwsmrvcSiIiS1VmLEiy0nvz3Hq/GEMJgQfjfkjEge4PX/XkJRLy69s MQBlHA5odNCYvgdA4wDD9f4fR1FVlfwQwbgxgcOstEBhacThC OqqVzDDe14YhtdAxJ YfekYFL4BfBlS85lREMG txFCAxEl1zkCZCf0eDT89tEAQHTrNRABZW1KUEYQCctR uNeEJ07IIDBNV6fWIKyFXKeBYSrg9e Rh1eb9/7CKEDxIs5H4OzdL4dexfqW4Nu8QmU2Um6o3ow H0ugASO4B1GOO9WOJJrvRg1fAXhGEo4Zf0N ztQmBC8hzKEMohyH1r Dfh9O69zgjp1b/8D66csbZyrQs4AAAAASUVORK5CYII="
```

Comment: With your string a get an error: `crc corruption`.

Comment: Can you compare binary source and resulting image? I've tried to create this PNG image using your base64 string but without success.

Comment: `fileString` contains spaces. Usually, a space isn't in the "alphabet". That means, this is not proper base64. See also wiki [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the next:

```
File fileOut = new File("/home/xyz/fileOutPNG.png");
FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(fileOut, 
                 javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(fileString));
```

Comment: This is working, The main reason was that the String was somehow get changed in the way. So we figured that out and the image is working fine. Thanks